# How does one immediately start shutting down withouth menu cinnamon?

Tags: shutdown, 20.04, cinnamon

Most Linux desktops show you a menu, after choosing shutdown, which is quite weird.
Is there a way to make cinnamon go immediately shutdown after clicking the logo and not show any window or menu?
I have focal fossa, on Ubuntu desktop with the Cinnamon Desktop installed
I do not want to bind a button, just how I did it before, but without the menu

Comment: You haven't provided OS/release details, but maybe use a SysRq keys to tell kernel to shutdown system cleanly, or you could use terminal to enter command telling the system the same thing.

Comment: Create a custom shortcut to a command that shuts it down.  Faster than clicking anything.  For example you want Meta-X to shut down.  You can then bind that shortcut to shutdown -now

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: This might be solved to put the shutdown time on and put it to 0